# To INSERT values from CTE result

Tags: sqlite, insert, common-table-expression

I have 'SchoolYearStartEnd' table

```
CREATE TABLE SchoolYearStartEnd (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
    StartDate DATE,
    EndDate DATE
);
```

and the second 'SchoolYearsTeachingDays' table

```
CREATE TABLE SchoolYearsTeachingDays (
    aDate DATE PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE
);
```

which I want to fill out with dates from a CTE like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates(x) AS (
 SELECT (SELECT StartDate FROM SchoolYearStartEnd)
  UNION ALL
 SELECT DATE(x, '+1 DAYS') FROM dates WHERE x < (SELECT EndDate FROM SchoolYearStartEnd)
 )
 SELECT * FROM dates WHERE CAST(STRFTIME('%w',x) AS INTEGER) > 0
;
```

I tried with this code here:

```
INSERT INTO SchoolYearsTeachingDays (aDate) VALUES (
  WITH RECURSIVE dates(x) AS (
   SELECT (SELECT StartDate FROM SchoolYearStartEnd)
    UNION ALL
   SELECT DATE(x, '+1 DAYS') FROM dates WHERE x < (SELECT EndDate FROM SchoolYearStartEnd)
   )
  SELECT * FROM dates WHERE CAST(STRFTIME('%w',x) AS INTEGER) > 0 -- To exclude Sundays.
 ;
);
```

but without success. I get these errors:

```
Error: near "RECURSIVE": syntax error
Error: near ")": syntax error
```

So what am I missing here?

Best, Pal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are inserting from a SELECT query, you [must not use VALUES](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_insert.html):

```
INSERT INTO SchoolYearsTeachingDays (aDate)
WITH RECURSIVE dates(x) AS (...)
SELECT * FROM dates ...;
```